# blur background like ios default blury effect in android

Tags: android

I am trying to make a card view have a background like the default blury background in ios.
Below image from ios device :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are libraries that use scripts to render blurred images.
Try [Blurry](https://github.com/wasabeef/Blurry) library or you can search a bit on github

Comment: let me try it, if it works for me, i'll mark your answer.Thanks :)

Comment: there are plenty of other libs on github all use blur processing that differ each other by processing time and algo. you just have to choose which is faster or works better in your case.